# Safely run executable in Node

Tags: python, node.js, docker, sandbox, trusted-vs-untrusted

I found myself having to implement the following use case: I need to run a webapp in which users can submit C programs, which need to be run safely on my backend.

I'm trying to get this done using Node. In the past, I had to do something similar but the user-submitted code was JavaScript code, and I got away with using Node [vm2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vm2) module. Essentially, I would create a VM and call its `run` method with the user submitted code as a string argument, then collect the output and do whatever I had to.

I'm trying to understand if using the same moule could help me with C code as well. The idea would be to use `exec` to first call `gcc` and compile the user code. Afterwards, I would use a VM to run `exec` again, this time passing the generated executable as a result. Would this be safe?

I don't understand vm2 deeply enough to know whether the safety is only limited to executing JS code or if it can be trusted to also run any arbitrary shell command safely.

In case vm2 isn't appropriate, what would be another way to run an executable in a sandboxed fashion in Node? Feel free to also suggest Python-based solutions, if you know any. Please note that the code will still be executed in a separate container as the main app regardless, but I want to make extra sure users cannot easily just tear it down at their liking.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently experiencing the same challenge as you, trying to execute safely some untrusted code using spawn, so what I can tell you is that vm2 only works for JS/TS code, but can't control what happens to a new process created by spawn, fork or exec.

For now I haven't found any good solution, but I'm thinking of trying to run the process as a user with limited rights.

As you seem to have access to the C source code, I would advise you to search how to run untrusted C programs (in plain C), and see if you can manipulate the C code in order to have a safer environment from this point of view.